# Return values from Git commands (git status)

Tags: git

I'd like to have a script that runs `make` on all dirty directories for my source - is there a way to have what's output from `git status` be returned via cmd line values somehow?

Basically, I'd like to be able to pop a set of changes, and run this script to build each directory rather than navigating to each directory individually and building them.

Comment: @screenmutt Did you even read the question?

Comment: Yes. Read your only question in the post. "Is there a way to have what's output from `git status` be returned via cmd line values somehow?" That is the duplicate. If you are asking something else, then this is mistagged.

Comment: The suggested dup doesn't mention git anywhere -- thanks anyways though

Comment: That is not what you asked... You asked if there was a way to return values from commands. Which is what is explained in the post. I have edited your post to make it clear you are not asking about Ruby, but rather about git commands. Please take more care in tagging your questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```rb
dirs = `git diff --name-only | xargs dirname | sort -u`.lines.map(&:chomp)
puts dirs
```

Breaking down the pipeline:

- `git diff --name-only`: Lists the names of the modified files
- `xargs dirname`: Takes the list of files from stdin and outputs their directories (turns `foo/bar.c` into `foo`)
- `sort -u`: Removes duplicates from the list of directories.

On the ruby side:

- [`` `command` ``](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60): Runs the command (as in the shell) and returns its output (as a string)
- [`String#lines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-lines): Returns an array of the string split into lines
- [`String#chomp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-chomp): Removes any newline from the end of the string (`String#lines` doesn't).